# docker-compose transition from docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, migration

I have already created containers running in my server.
They were created through the command line with `docker run`.

I believe using docker-compose will result in a more portable containers (I don't need to `docker run` all containers in a different server, only put the same file).

Is there a way to translate the already created containers to a docker-compose file?
In their website (https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/), it is mentioned to use `docker-compose migrate_to_labels`, but it seems the command is not working in the latest version of docker-compose

Comment: How many container are we talking about? Since docker-compose sometimes has a slightly different approach than docker, it might be best to do this by hand. In case you have many containers you probably need to look at Kubernetes instead of docker-compose.

Comment: @BertC around 10-20 containers. I believe Kubernetes is more an approach for multiple hosts running containers. I currently have one single host, that's why I chose docker-compose. But correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not an expert.

Comment: In case of one host then you would be fine with DockerCompose. Still, I would do the conversion by hand because sometimes docker-compose just works a bit different than docker.